# Richfaces modalPanel load with Ajax

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I use richfaces in my project and particularly the tag rich:modalPanel which allows to display popups in pages.

So to do this, I include my popup like this:

```
<ui:include src="popup.xhtml" />
```

This popup contains this code:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="sra" width="400" autosized="true" left="100" >
...
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Finally to display the popup, I do this in the main page:

```
<a4j:commandLink id="linkSRA" value="#{msg['SRA']}" action="#{controller.checkSRA}" oncomplete="#{rich:component('sra')}.show()" />
```

All work fine but my problem is the next:

In a page, I have many popup and each popup is included in the main page. The weight of this one is very big for nothing. So, how can I do to load the popup's content in ajax when I want to load a popup ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-render the panel content via some action and then open the modal in oncomplete=".."

Comment: So I must stock the rerender value in my bean ? A boolean which indicate if the content must be rendered or not ?

Comment: Just to understand better, do you want to rerender modal panel content or the actual modal panel?

Comment: With your suggestion, I think rerender the actual modal panel which is displayed when you click on a link (or any event which display this modal).

Answer (score 0):

I have write a little article : "How to create a stateful Richfaces popup" where I show how to create a popup controller. This popup controller allows to replace all the modal tags with a few lines :

```
<a4j:outputPanel binding="#{popupController.popupContainer}" id="popupContainer">
<c:forEach items="#{popupController.popups}" var="popup">
<f:subview id="popupView#{popup.id}">
<ui:include src="#{popup.uri}">
<ui:param name="popupBean" value="#{popup.popupBean}"/>
</ui:include>
</f:subview>
</c:forEach>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

The article is available [here](http://nlabrot.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-create-stateful-richfaces-popup.html#more). Sorry, it is too long to be paste directly here.

Comment: I'll go to read your article but I have a comment on your snapshot. You use c:forEach tag but sometimes, conflicts appear between richfaces tags and jstl tags.

Comment: I read your article, the idea is interesting. I have some questions, why do you use the key word synchronized for add or remove method ? For your popup id, you use an integer, but in production with many users, you can overflow the integer size ?

Comment: I do not have any conflicts with the c:forEach.  


You right, the int can overflow. IT may be better to use a long. For 10 popup/s the int will overflow until 7 years.


I use the synchronized keyword because users tend to click more than once. The "add" and "remove" methods use the popups list which should be unmodified until the end of these methods. I agree it could be improved.